# PowerShell script to access Oracle system views

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, powershell

I am using PowerShell script to access oracle 11g's system views 
as  SELECT COUNT (*) AS COUNT FROM v$session but I keep getting "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"

I have created a user with sysdba privilege and all connections are a fine as I can even query other schemas without errors, but I only get error when I access any system views. can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

I also gave permission as "GRANT SELECT on v_$session TO mynewuser even tho I know its not needed if the user has sysdba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What powershell syntax are you using?

If you do not enclose the select between single quotes, Powershell will treat it like a variable. If that's the problem, please try:

```
$command.CommandText = 'SELECT COUNT (*) AS COUNT FROM v$session'
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to grant the `DBA` role to the user. `SYSDBA` does not give you the right to these objects.

Comment: yes I also given DBA role to this new user and still no luck

Comment: Can you access the `v$session` view with that user from another tool? Also, when you want to use the `v_$session` then you must add the owner: `sys.v_$session`.

Comment: yes I can connect using TOAD with that user and access it with out any problem, I also tried with sys.

Comment: Means that the problem most likely comes from the powershell. I cannot help you with that. I am more a Linux guy.